# windows 8 app page that has list and details

Tags: windows-8

I am now designing a page for a windows 8 app.
the page has 2 parts, the left part will be like a list, when user select one item in the list, the right part will show the content based on the selection.
but I want to select different item in the left will display the different data in the right. For example, maybe select first item in the list, some text blocks will display on the right. select second item , an image will display on the right.

the data in the behind is a class which has some properties. I just want show this properties based on the selection in the list

so how to implement this? anyone has any idea?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the item template, create controls in separate panels for each different data type: text, image, video, etc. Then you can use a converter on each panel to inspect the data that it is bound to and show/hide the panels where appropriate.  Depending on your data source, you might be evaluating either the class type or a property that contains an enumerated value that reveals the type, or maybe some more complex evaluation of the state of the class's properties.

Answer (score 0):

One of the templates that comes with Visual Studio Express for Windows 8 supports this list and details view - look at the [Split App template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh768232.aspx#split_project_template_for_windows_store_apps).

For more information, see:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh738343.aspx

Comment: I've checked that template. the content displayed on the right are similar and have the same structure. but I want to show different data and different structure.